# React native navigation for react-native version 0.60.4

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am trying to make a navigation in react native version 0.60.4 but i am getting many issues doing this...can anybody help?

i have followed some sites providing guides for making react navigation but i am getting errors

can any body show the full methodology of making a navigation in the current version

Comment: Could you please attach your error screen or error message?

Comment: Actually i am not getting any kind of syntax errors ....it is occurring due to version miss match or some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Some tutorials stick with old react navigation versions. Just follow the link below to get a brand new hello world with the newest react navigation package.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html

Comment: thank u so much Vijantedo i'll try this and respond you back :)